# Table View Controller not showing content from asset folder, or any content at all really

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As a complete novice, I have followed the tutorial linked below to design a new View of a very similar design. [Link Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSryf0YJHHk)

Ultimately, I want to display a collection view with an image displayed above a label naming the image above. eg. A picture of a cow with "Beef" displayed below. A chicken, and "Chicken" below, you get the drift.

I've created a `UICollectionViewController`, called My Meals, as a segue from the main storyboard's Entry Point. The `UICollectionViewController`, My Meals, is embedded into a Navigation Controller. This View has its own Cocoa Touch Class  which is "MyMealsViewController.swift" as seen in the identity inspector.

I've created a Cocoa Touch Class called "CollectionViewCell.swift". I've created a single cell with a `UIImageView` and a Label on the Collection View. Both the `UIImageView` and Label have been connected to the CollectionView.swift, as below:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainIngredientImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainIngredientLabel: UILabel!
}
```

The cell has also been given the class `CollectionViewCell` as seen in the identity inspector.

The code I have taken, hopefully character by character from the video is here:

```
import UIKit

class MyMealsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let ingredients = ["Beef", "Chicken", "Duck", "Lamb", "Pork", "Saugage", "Seafood", "Turkey", "Other"]

    let ingredientsImages: [UIImage] = [


        UIImage(named: "Beef")!,
        UIImage(named: "Chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "Duck")!,
        UIImage(named: "Lamb")!,
        UIImage(named: "Pork")!,
        UIImage(named: "Sausage")!,
        UIImage(named: "Seafood")!,
        UIImage(named: "Turkey")!,
        UIImage(named: "Other")!,

    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ingredients.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.mainIngredientLabel.text = ingredients[indexPath.item]
        cell.mainIngredientImage.image = ingredientsImages[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Images I am hoping to be used are named as per the code, and they are all sitting and waiting in the Assets.xassets folder.

The issue I am facing, is that when I run the simulator, the page will load, the background colour will load. However that is it. There are no labels. No images. I'd understand if there were labels, but there is nothing appearing to do with the cell.

I have attempted changing the `UIImageView` from Aspect Fill, Aspect Fit and Scale to Fill. All to no avail.

Please can someone recommend where I have gone astray? Yes, I also understand that I have to start somewhere, and this video may not be the easiest to follow but it looks like what I am hoping to create! Any questions, or anything I have omitted in my novice state please ask.

Comment: If your images are missing, you should see a warning in the console. Are you sure your datasource delegates are being called the right number if times?

Comment: I have no warnings, yellow triangles or red circles when during the build or simulation. As a complete novice, are you able to expand on what you mean please?

Comment: In viewdidLoad try adding collectionview.datasource = self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the "two important things" he mentions that he forgot at [7:25 in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSryf0YJHHk&t=445) – that is, you need to set your collection view's `dataSource` and `delegate` to your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This has now loaded only part of the images, but no labels. The images are very tall, the entire height of a view, and only showing the pixels from the left side of the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you need to further debug your code and storyboard, as you have not provided enough information to determine what the cause of this new problem could be. Maybe you haven't set the `itemSize` of your collection view layout and your cells are too small. Maybe your images are too large and they're overlaying and obscuring the labels. It could be any number of things.

Comment: You were correct, the images were too large. I have manually changed the item sizes to correspond with the UIImageView size on the scene. The items now appear in the correct size, with the labels shown below. Thanks for your help